# How to disabled the other legends when clicking the first legend in echarts

Tags: javascript, typescript, echarts

Here's the code:

```
option = {
    title: {
        text: '堆叠区域图'
    },
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis',
        axisPointer: {
            type: 'cross',
            label: {
                backgroundColor: '#6a7985'
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        data: ['邮件营销', '联盟广告', '视频广告', '直接访问', '搜索引擎'],
        selected: {
            '邮件营销': false
        }
    },
    toolbox: {
        feature: {
            saveAsImage: {}
        }
    },
    grid: {
        left: '3%',
        right: '4%',
        bottom: '3%',
        containLabel: true
    },
    xAxis: [
        {
            type: 'category',
            boundaryGap: false,
            data: ['周一', '周二', '周三', '周四', '周五', '周六', '周日']
        }
    ],
    yAxis: [
        {
            type: 'value'
        }
    ],
    series: [
        {
            name: '邮件营销',
            type: 'line',
            stack: '总量',
            areaStyle: {},
            data: [120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210]
        },
        {
            name: '联盟广告',
            type: 'line',
            stack: '总量',
            areaStyle: {},
            data: [220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310]
        },
        {
            name: '视频广告',
            type: 'line',
            stack: '总量',
            areaStyle: {},
            data: [150, 232, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410]
        },
        {
            name: '直接访问',
            type: 'line',
            stack: '总量',
            areaStyle: {},
            data: [320, 332, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320]
        },
        {
            name: '搜索引擎',
            type: 'line',
            stack: '总量',
            label: {
                normal: {
                    show: true,
                    position: 'top'
                }
            },
            areaStyle: {},
            data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320]
        }
    ]
};
```

What I want to do is when I click the `邮件营销` it should show the series and disabled/hide all the other legend except the `邮件营销` that I clicked. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOgcV.png)

and when I click the other legend the `邮件营销` will disabled/hide the series and it will show the series that I clicked.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQk4i.png)

but when I clicked the `邮件营销` again it will hide/disabled the other legends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you need a chart where you want to see the details of only clicked legend. When user click on legend A, then type A should be visible on screen. And if user clicks on legend B, then type B data should be visible only visible on screen.

We can you legendselectedchange event to detect the change event and correspondingly set the chart. I have attached the code below, I hope it helps you.

```js
 // 基于准备好的dom，初始化echarts实例
 var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

option = {
    title: {
        text: '折线图堆叠'
    },
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis'
    },
    legend: {
        data: ['邮件营销', '联盟广告', '视频广告', '直接访问', '搜索引擎']
    },
    grid: {
        left: '3%',
        right: '4%',
        bottom: '3%',
        containLabel: true
    },
    toolbox: {
        feature: {
            saveAsImage: {}
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        boundaryGap: false,
        data: ['周一', '周二', '周三', '周四', '周五', '周六', '周日']
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: '邮件营销',
            type: 'line',
            stack: '总量',
            data: [120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210]
        },
        {
            name: '联盟广告',
            type: 'line',
            stack: '总量',
            data: [220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310]
        },
        {
            name: '视频广告',
            type: 'line',
            stack: '总量',
            data: [150, 232, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410]
        },
        {
            name: '直接访问',
            type: 'line',
            stack: '总量',
            data: [320, 332, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320]
        },
        {
            name: '搜索引擎',
            type: 'line',
            stack: '总量',
            data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320]
        }
    ]
};

// use configuration item and data specified to show chart
        myChart.setOption(option);

myChart.on('legendselectchanged', function (params) {
    console.log(params);
    selectGraph(params);
    unselectGrap(params);
});

function selectGraph(params) {
    myChart.dispatchAction({
    type: 'legendSelect',
    // legend name
    name: params.name,
})
}

function unselectGrap(params) {
    for (const legend in params.selected) {
        if(legend !== params.name) {
                myChart.dispatchAction({
                    type: 'legendUnSelect',
                    // legend name
                    name: legend,
                })
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/3.7.2/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: how do I apply here.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-echarts-atksnr?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Please use this link for angular implementation - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u7kuny

I hope it will help